# How to crop out a circle inside marked area?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I wrote code that can mark out circles around these 5 yellow-colored experimental conditions. A piece of paper with 5 black circles will be provided, and the experimental conditions will go into the interior of the circles. So from a cv2 program I can trace out the black circles outside, as seen in this [image].

How should I then write a code that can crop out for instance 30% of the interior circle (or something like 20% of the big circle's diameter so I will just obtain only the insides of the experimental condition. [image: something like this]
Then I would like to crop out just the (red interior circles) as 5 separate images. Would this be possible? Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get the centers of each circle (ellipse) and their radii.  Compute a circles radius of 20-30% as desired. Draw a white filled circle on a black background as a mask for each circle. Apply the mask to the input image to blacken out the outside. Save that image. Then go to the next circle and do the same thing.

Comment: How would I draw a white filled circle as a mask in the background? Would you be able to provide a bit of code? Thank you

Comment: Make a black image (np.zeros), then draw a white filled circle using cv2.circle().  Read the documentation for each if you still do not understand. Or search Google for examples.